# Get the jqXhr.responseText on a jQuery getJSON request using JSONP

Tags: jquery, jsonp, jqxhr

I am writing a diagnostic site to test our server methods.
One of the things I would like to see is the HTTP status code, and the actual payload returned.

When I make a CORS request by using $.ajax, I can see the jqXhr.responseText to see the payload, but when I use $.getJSON to make a JSONP request, jqXhr.responseText is undefined.

Is there any way to see the HTTP payload when using $.getJSON with jsonp?

```
function callJavascript(url, callback) {
    var closedData;
    var jqXhr = $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        closedData = data;
    })
    .success(function() {
        $('#statusCode').text(jqXhr.status); //200
        $('#statusText').text(jqXhr.statusText); //success
        //this is undefined
        $('#responseText').text(jqXhr.responseText); 
        callback(closedData);
    });
};


function someCall()
{
    var callback = function(data) {
        //snip... will pop UI with json object returned
    };
    callJavascript('http://myurl?callback=?', callback);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using `.done` instead of `.success` due to deprecation.

Within the `.success` callback (or `.done`) there are three parameters: parsed response text, status text, and xhr object.

```
function callJavascript(url, callback) {
    var closedData;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        closedData = data;
    })
    .done(function(parsedResponse,statusText,jqXhr) {
        $('#statusCode').text(jqXhr.status); //200
        $('#statusText').text(jqXhr.statusText); //success
        //this should not be undefined
        $('#responseText').text(jqXhr.responseText); 
        console.log(parsedResponse);
        callback(closedData);
    });
};
```

Here's a fiddle where you can see the full `console.log` of the arguments.

http://jsfiddle.net/SDUEj/

Comment: Yes, in that jsfiddle the responseText is populated, but only when using the jsfiddle echo endpoint.  if i change it to use mine it is undefined.  I can even use my old method to get responseText (where .success closes around jqXhr) using the /echo/jsonp/... the only difference i can see is that when going to my url i am cross-domain.  Could this be part of same-origin policy in Chrome?

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/collinsauve/5GQ6s/  replace myurl in 2nd last line with a cross-domain call... responseText will be undefined

Comment: seeing this behaviour with the same fiddle in all of Chrome, FF and IE

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't using jsonp. Here's a better example using jsonp. http://jsfiddle.net/SDUEj/2/ It confirms that there is no responseText. I suspect that is due to the fact that it is a jsonp request and not a typical ajax request. It is made using a `<script>` tag. I guess you could generate responseText from the returned object using `JSON.stringify(arguments[0])`