# How to set 'status'-parameter of the $.post()-function in aspx-response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, asp.net

I have a HTML-page with some JS-code in it, which is loaded from the Android `WebView`. This JavaScript uses the [jQuery-post-function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to call the `HandleAndroidJSON.aspx`-site with data, and return a callback-function with a `data`-, `status`- (and `jqXhr`-) parameter:

```
function syncWithServer() {
    var dataToSend = Android.getDataToSend();
    $.post("HandleAndroidJSON.aspx", { data: dataToSend }, callbackDataFromServer);
}

function callbackDataFromServer(data, status) {
    Android.setDataFromServer(data, status);
}
```

The "Android"-variable is a `JavaScriptInterface`created in Android that makes it possible to call Android-methods from JS.

In my `HandleAndroidJSON.aspx.cs`-file I write a response depending on the data I receive from Android:

```
public partial class HandleAndroidJSON : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        // Read request parameter and deserialize JSON data.
        string jsonDataFromClient = Request.Params["data"];

        // ... Do stuff with the data ...

        if (error != null)
        {
            //This goes into the data-parameter of the callbackFunction
            Response.Write(error); 
            //Response.Status = "403 Error"; //This seems to only be HTTP-status responses,
                                   //not the one used as parameter in the callback-function
        }
        else
        {
            //This does too
            Response.Write(jsonDataToSend); 
        }
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

The `Response.Write()`-method returns in the the `data`-parameter in the callback-function as intended, but I cannot seem to set the `status`-parameter - **it always returns the same string**: "success" and doesn't change if I set the `Response.Status`-property.

So the question is simply, how do I set the `status`-parameter of the `callbackDataFromServer`-function (that is called from the jQuery-post-function) from the aspx.cs-code?

**EDIT**: I'm not talking about [status-codes for HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Setting the `StatusDescription`-, `StatusCode`- and the `Status`- properties, of the `Response`-property, doesn't change the `status`-parameter of the callback-function.

**EDIT2**: I don't think handling the status-parameter in the JavaScript-code solves the problem because I would have to validate the data in Android again anyway (since JavaScript-injection would be possible to do to avoid the error handling). I would like to pass it on to the Android-method via the status-parameter, in the `callbackDataFromServer`-function, as the current code indicates.

**EDIT3**: Even though I can't seem to find a straight answer to whether it's possible to set the `status`-parameter from the aspx-code, it seems that the only thing you can change beside the `data`-parameter is the `jqXhr.status` property, which can be set be the `Response.StatusCode` property in the aspx-site.

There's also the `jqXhr.statusText` property which holds a string, but it seems to be the default text, based on the statuscode, and not the `Response.StatusDescription` (setting the statusCode to 200 and the statusDescription to "success" returned as "OK", which is default for the statusCode 200).

This is the topic I was reading: [Get the jqXhr.responseText on a jQuery getJSON request using JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949146/get-the-jqxhr-responsetext-on-a-jquery-getjson-request-using-jsonp)

**EDIT4**: I now figured out that setting the `StatusCode` to a value, that implies something went wrong, will result in no data being sent, even though the `Response.Write()`-method has been called, which defeats the purpose I'm trying to achieve.

The proper question would then be: **How can I properly pass on the error text (from ASP.NET, through jQuery) if something went wrong, instead of the data? And how can I ensure that the data I'm transfering is either an error or JSONData?**
I figure the simple way is just to check if the data starts with a "{" or "[" but I feel like it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: status codes are set by server

Comment: @John So this means I cannot access it? Are you sure?

Comment: you can surely access it but not set it, as you stated in your question

Comment: If you're sure about this, you should post an answer.

Comment: i have posted it already `:)`

Answer (score 2):

inorder to get the status code you can use the `status` property of the third argument of success call back `jqXHR`, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prD5c/

so your function looks like

```
function callbackDataFromServer(data, status,jqXhr) {
    console.log(jqXhr.status);
    Android.setDataFromServer(data, status);
}
```

you can use the `statusCode` like

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    202: function() {
      alert("success");
    },
    403:function(){
      alert(error);
    }
  }
});
```

as you are using `$.post` you can define this in the `ajaxSetup` like

```
$.ajaxSetup({
      statusCode: {
        202: function() {
          alert("success");
        },
        403:function(){
          alert(error);
        }
      }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I need the status parameter to differ in the `setDataFromServer()`-call, so I can differ actions based on that status. This, to my understanding, just puts the status of the third parameter to the log accessible in tools like Firebug. If not, how do I set the jqXhr-parameter from the aspx.cs-code?

Comment: by status you mean status code i.e `200` or `403` or the status description `success` or `error`?

Comment: The status-parameter returns as a string into Android. I don't want to handle the status in the JavaScript if I can avoid it. I want as little function visible in the JavaScript as possible. I edited my question to attempt to clarify this.

Comment: To better answer your question: It's neither the status code or the status description. It's the status-parameter that you told me that I can't set from the aspx-code, as far as I understood.

Comment: I really don't understand this answer, if you want it marked as an answer, please elaborate how it solves my problem.
And anyone else upvoting this answer seems to get it as well, so please, if you understand this answer, you're welcome to elaborate as well.